# Customer payment portal

Tags: gratis, online-payment, enterprise-portal

I am looking for something free for commercial use, preferably PHP, but I will accept anything.

It should allow users to register, and to purchase services which my software provides. User should, obviously, be able to see their purchases & history, choose between subscription levels (defined by me), etc.

The software should write to a database, with strong preference for MySql, which I can then access from the main software to determine whether usage is allowed.

It should be able to interface with PayPal and credit card payments; bank transfers would be a bonus, as would other payment methods.

While it should run smoothly with only customer interaction, it would be nice if I could have super-user access and be able to administer it.

I am looking for something widely used, well tested and secure. I am sure there are a ton of features that I haven’t thought of, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using one of drupal's modules: either [drupal commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) (more flexible/newer) or [drupal ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) (simpler but older).

- registration of user is standard on drupal
- purchase of services: you can set up the service as a "product" in either module. if you give example of your service I can guide further.
- user can see their purchases & history when using either module
- the different subscription levels will be setup as "products", which can then be linked to drupal "roles" to grant access to services etc.
- payment methods: both have paypal and many other payment modules
- the admin user can amend things
- Also, given that it is open souce, you can write custom modules if necessary, or choose from many of the available modules to add more functionality.

I have used both in the past for something similar.

Comment: I have to upvote you for a good answer. I was afraid the answer would be Drupal, as it has always run slowly when I used it in the past. But that is probably because they just give me a share of a server. If I used this for commercial porpoises I Imagen I would have a dedicated server. Thanks for the good advice, and anyone reading this should be aware of your sister site ... https://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. For drupal solutions, I recommend at least a VPS account. That's what I used. You can then upgrade to fully dedicated server if volume/load warrants it.

Comment: Sorry to sound dumb, but what is a VPS account?

Comment: Virtual Private Server - better than a shared account but below a fully dedicated... I suppose its like having your own server on a big machine, but with "fixed" resources. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server and have a look at differences on a provider like inmotionhosting.com which I have used in past.